# google maps geometry library

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is my problem, I am testing an app that find routes between two points, in my localhost tests everything works fine, but when I upload to my server this error shows up:

This service requires an API key.  For more information on authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

I am getting my google maps library, this way:

> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry

So, I have some questions, if I require a key to use this API, why can I use it in my localhost server? Can I use this API without key?

Please help

Comment: The key is now required (sensor is no longer required)..

Comment: thanks for answering, but, this works fine in my localhost

Comment: Local host may be different from publicly available domains (and it may be one of the "grandfathered" domains).

Comment: ummm, so i have to get a key anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There were some changes in authentication and usage limits announced on June 22, 2016.

You can read this article on Geo Developers Blog:

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html

The API key is now mandatory. The localhost is "grandfathered" domain.

Comment: Thanks xomena, I didn´t know about this changes, I will have to make a more simple solution. Thanks for your answer.